# \contentsline with 4 parameters

Tags: table-of-contents, latex-base

I have a document whcih .toc file looks like this:

```
\contentsline {chapter}{Prefácio}{vii}{chapter*.2}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}História}{1}{chapter.1}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {2}Revisão}{7}{chapter.2}
```

This looks strange to me, because according to the `source2e.pdf` document, '\contentsline' has only 3 arguments. Can someone explain to me what is this 4th elements? To me it looks like an automatically generated label. Other documents processed similarly has not this 4th parameters. The class I use doesn't load any package related to TOC creation/redefinition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a redefined `\contentsline` by package `hyperref`, which needs to know the link target name for the entry in the table of contents. The target name is stored in the fourth argument.