# Can I generate a table of contents directly from a .toc file?

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm in the situation where I have a .toc file, and I just want to compile this to an actual table of contents without having access to the .tex file from which the .toc file was generated. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an approach that is neither professional nor time-saving, but a possibility.

Given a .toc file with contents like this:

```
\select@language {american}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}{Introduction}}{1}{chapter.1}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {2}{Main Part}}{2}{chapter.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.1}{Some Section}}{2}{section.2.1}
```

Copy the contents in a LaTeX file (containing the lines required to compile it, like `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}`). Afterwards, delete all unnecessary lines, like `\select@language {american}`. The LaTeX file should now look like this (*not compileable*):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}{Introduction}}{1}{chapter.1}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {2}{Main Part}}{2}{chapter.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.1}{Some Section}}{2}{section.2.1}

\end{document}
```

As a final step, delete the text like `{chapter.1}` and `{section.2.1}`.
The file will look like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}{Introduction}}{1}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {2}{Main Part}}{2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.1}{Some Section}}{2}

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:
[image: Table of Contents[1]]

**Edit**: Instead of deleting text like `{chapter.1}`, you can add to the preamble:

```
\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline
\renewcommand{\contentsline}[4]{\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}}
```

which redefines the `\contentsline` command.

Comment: what is the difference with the initial lines in he '.toc' file and your last part of the answer? Why not use an `\include` statement (maybe after renaming the '.toc' file and redefining the \contentsline (see also for a pointer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333880/contentsline-with-4-parameters/333881#333881).

Comment: I didn't realize it was that easy! Thanks.

Comment: @albert: You are right, I forgot to delete the lines in the code. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is similar to [another of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346640/107497).  At it's most basic, you can simply do

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\input{file.toc}
\end{document}
```

The trouble ends up being with packages that modify how the table of contents works (and how unaccessible the original tex source is).  If `hyperref` was originally loaded, you'll need
`\usepackage[draft]{hyperref}`
in the preamble.  If a language option (`babel` or `polyglosia`) put utf characters into the toc, you'll need to adjust accordingly.

Comment: I was noticing a problem with hyperref. Thanks!